Installing a .NET 8 service via sc.exe - and then getting the Service path in c#
So I have built my .NET 8 Windows Service, and used the "Publish" option before deploying the
Service to my local - using the Single File "self-contained" option. I then copied that folder to one of our servers for deployment.
In PowerShell as follows:
sc.exe create "Mqtt Service" binpath="C:\dev\projects\..\NotificationServiceCore\bin\Release\net8.0-windows\publish\MyServiceCore.exe"


But in my code, I need to get the path to that deployed service - NOT the Windows temp folder.
This for example does NOT give it to me - System.AppContext.BaseDirectory; - it returns c:\windows\temp\.net\..
But I have caught the exception when trying to load my certificate file:
2024-06-14 12:59:35 (null) [5]  ERROR Certificate Exception in WsSecureClientOptions(). Check app config settings. The system cannot find the file specified.
2024-06-14 12:59:35 (null) [5]  DEBUG Path to Certificate File - C:\Windows\TEMP\.net\NotificationServiceCore\pxsSvFJpErHm9e18vOpihtHD3i7O1g4=\certificate2024.pfx

Why the file exception? It's because we do NOT include that certificate.pjx in our project build. We have a post-build event which copies that file to $(OutDir)
cd $(ProjectDir)
xcopy "..\certificate\*.*" "$(OutDir)" /F /Y

The issue here is that the pfx certificate file is not in that `c:\Windows\Temp.net..." folder.
And this is how I resolve to the Base Directory in my code:
string appBaseDir = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;


How do you publish your app? Is it singlefile?

Have you tried working with Environment.ProcessPath (getting directory from it) or similar with Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;?

@GuruStron I have the "produce single file" checked, and sometimes it create a single DLL file, and sometimes not. I can't figure out why. This could be part of my issue.

For single file check out this answer? maybe it would be helpful.

"and sometimes not. I can't figure out why." - TBH do not know here, it's been some time since I've played with single file deployments. Without access to the full [mre] I'm afraid I will not be able to help.

@GuruStron - w/out the "single file" option, it produces many more files in my output folder. But it seems to make a difference if I build WITHOUT the SingleFile option...I just deployed to my server.

"w/out the "single file" option, it produces many more files in my output folder." - yes, since it will need to copy all the dependencies dlls for project to run. And for single file deployment it will combine them into a single file.

@GuruStron in all fairness, if you would post an answer I will select it. When you brought up the Single File option, I discovered that it was exactly my issue. Without the single file "self-contained' option, I was able to deploy successfully - and the BaseDir worked as expected ! No more TEMP folder issues, etc.

Bottom line: Do NOT choose the "self-contained" and "Produce single file" options.
Instead, choose "Framework-dependent" and "win-x64" (or whatever's appropriate for your envir).
FYI: Now System.AppContext.BaseDirectory will indeed return the directory in which you have installed your Win service (i.e. and not the temp folder that I had previously seen with the self-contained option).

Your build files (.dll, .exe, .dll.config) will be deployed to ..\publish\win-x64 folder.
